# Accessing collection documents in onSnapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to access a list of documents in a collection with onSnapshot. Previously I had this code:

```
const users = [];
var snapshot = await store.collection("users").get()
      const users = [];
      snapshot.docs.forEach((s) => {
        if(!interacted.includes(s.data().email)){
          users.push(s.data());
        }
});
```

Now I am trying to use firebase's modular format and am trying the following but it's not properly getting the data from each document.

```
  const usersCollection = collection(store, 'users');
  const snapshot = await getDocs(usersCollection);
  const users = [];

   onSnapshot(usersCollection, (docSnapshot) => {
          console.log("EXISTS", docSnapshot.data())
            docSnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                if(!interacted.includes(doc.data().email)){
                  users.push(doc.data());
                }
          })
      })
```

How can I get each document and push it to the users array?

Comment: Your question is basically saying "it doesn't work" without explaining what exactly isn't working the way you expect.  Please edit the question to show your debugging details - explain what you are observing and how it's different than what you expect. There should be enough information in the question that anyone can duplicate your results.

Comment: @DougStevenson it doesn’t work means that the data isn’t accessed at all where as it was in the previous firebase version

Comment: Please edit the question to show your debugging details - explain what you are observing and how it's different than what you expect. There should be enough information in the question that anyone can duplicate your results.